# Passwordless scp from Ubuntu Server to Windows PC

Tags: server, ssh, scp

I'm running Windows10 for my Pc and Ubuntu Server 18.04. I'm able to copy files from Ubuntu server to my Windows using SCP. However, I would like to be passwordless. These are what I have done:

1. generate key pair using `ssh-keygen` in my ubuntu server
2. copy my `id_rsa.pub` to the .ssh folder named authorized_keys in my windows 10 .

I was trying to ssh to my Windows from Ubuntu using `ssh mypc@192.168.x.x`

However, I still need to enter password.

Below is the output of  `ssh -v mypc@192.168.x.x`

> OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 201
>
> debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>
> debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
>
> debug1: Connecting to 192.168.34.115 [192.168.34.115] port 22.
>
> debug1: Connection established.
>
> debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type 0 debug1:
>
> key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
>
> debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
>
> debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type
>
> debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
>
> debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
>
> debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
>
> debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
>
> debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
>
> debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
> debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
>
> debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.34.115:22 as 'student'
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>
> debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
>
> debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
>
> debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
>
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
>
> debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:dTQg72DCXDCJWctbzfVcaECPMXKUQEWxgreuZQQLD+8
>
> debug1: Host '192.168.34.115' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
>
> debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
>
> debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>
> debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
>
> debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
>
> debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>
> debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:AldtOhWR54JDirM1ejw7v3NcLo5xoME6S7G4VTbOgWs /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
>
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
>
> debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
>
> debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
>
> debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
>
> debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
>
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
>
> debug1: Next authentication method: password`

Anything I did incorrectly? Thanks for help.

Comment: Messages "No such file or directory" for various `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_*` files suggest that you don't have key files in the proper directory on the server where SSH is looking for them.

Comment: There shouldn't be a **file** `id_rsa.pub` in the **folder** named `authorized_keys`. There should be a **file** named `authorized_keys` that contains a copy of the contents of your `id_rsa.pub` file.